# Why does Java 8 from Netbeans hijack Java 7 running in my browser?

Tags: java, google-chrome, netbeans

Java 7 *is* my system default JRE. All of my web browsers are configured to invoke JRE7 on a new instance, as default.
Netbeans fires up Java 8 on a new instance, as its 'isolated' default (isolated in terms as from the rest of the system).

Consider scenario: Chrome is up and running fine, then I'm inspired to code and then open Netbeans. When Netbeans loads, Chrome's java gets funky - I can no longer interact with javascript applets (such as chatango handshakes don't happen, scrollbars become non-responsive, any a host of other anomalies occur).  I take the step to reinitialize Chrome, and frames either don't load at all, time out, or stack out of the page's "defined" layout.

Keep in mind, I am NOT (purposely) running any java 8 programs outside of Netbeans.

Why does this occur? My suspicion is that JRE8 replaces the pointers for API calls in the system env.. I would have assumed that the JRE sandbox would have extended to that machine version's libraries, but that seems not to be the case. Is this a fundamental incompatibility, or a bug? Must I suffer it until my choice browser developer releases a Java 8+ compatible browser? Am I the only one that even experiences this?

(I appreciate any feedback that is thoughtful, and not around the lines of LMGTFY or other useless quips)

Thanks!

Comment: Java*Script* applets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen something similar happen with Firefox. The reason was a faulty graphics card driver.

Both applications, Firefox and a Java application were using **3D acceleration** which resulted in a lot of visual artefacts and crashes later on.

You could try the following:

- Disabling any acceleration features in Netbeans (Use `sun.java2d.noddraw` and `sun.java2d.d3d`)
- Disable acceleration features in Chrome.
- Update your graphics card driver

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I reset all of chrome's features to default and further disabled the following (if not already disabled by default): "Accelerated overflow scroll," "Universal accelerated overflow scroll," "Gesture Tap Highlighting," "Enable pinch virtual viewport," "Enable touch initiated drag and drop,"

Comment: These changes did have the effect to greatly and immediately speed up chrome's URL resolving and page rendering, and the issue has been considerably reduced, but the underlying issue seems to remain.

In this "disable features fix" (thanks to your suggestion), I no longer get a complete lockout of the scrollbars, nor do java frames fail into a non-resolve or infinite loading loop state.
There's what appears to be a 'lockout' on my mouse as I attempt to click and hold the scrollbar's 'scrollblock', but I can click the scrollbar's arrows and use my mouse wheel to scroll, now.

Comment: I must say that I hibernate often and I'm suspicious that there could be cache or memory address corruption during hibernation/sleep/awake transition cycling, but I have done a few hard reboots and the new condition sometimes occurs after a fresh boot (with no invocation of Netbeans)... However, since my main issue has been worked around, I'll mark your advise as solving my main issue (unless you have more to add). Thank you, Daniel!